# Is there an SVG version of the Finder icon from macOS Big Sur?

Tags: finder, icon, big-sur

In a project I'm working on, we have icons to represent different platforms. Since we support both macOS and iOS, we don't want to use the Apple logo for either because it's ambiguous between those two platforms. Currently we are using the Finder icon from macOS Big Sur.

However, we are looking to replace the platform icons with SVG files (preferably lightweight ones), so that they will look great at any resolution, while being smaller in file size. Is there any way I could get an SVG version of this icon without re-creating it?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to just trace over the macOS Big Sur Finder icon in Inkscape, and it turned out pretty great.

It's simplified compared to the PNG that Apple provides, there's no shadows around the icon and no shading on the eyes and mouth, but that might not be noticeable anyway at small scales. I compressed the SVG file using the `svgcleaner` tool, it's 1,729 bytes.

Comment: I assume you are aware of https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html, especially the use of a "Apple-owned graphic symbol, logo, or icon" in your own products.

Comment: If that is the case, then wouldn't using the official Finder icon also violate this (as we already are)? If we are violating copyright, I would greatly appreciate it if you could open a bug report about this https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues

Comment: Good point, removed the other icon as well.

Comment: IANAL so I wouldn't know whether you actually violate copyright or not, I'm also not in any way related to Apple so I don't really have a stake here.